# Old quantum theory and the energy levels of the hydrogen atom bounded states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, orbitals, semiclassical

I'm trying to obtain the energy levels of the hydrogen atom using the old quantum theory. In particular using the Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization rules

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\int p_i dq_i = n_ih
\end{equation}

First of all I have considered the hamiltonian with a potential of the form $V(r) = -\frac{e^2}{r}$ so

\begin{equation}
H = \frac{p_r^2}{2m}+\frac{l^2}{2mr^2}-\frac{e^2}{r} \equiv E
\end{equation}

where $p_r$ is the radial momentum $p_r = m\dot{r}$ and $l = mr^2\dot{\phi}$ is the angular momentum. For the angular variable, using the Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization I easily obtain
\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi} l d\phi = 2\pi l = nh \rightarrow l = n\hbar
\end{equation}
for the radial variable I can obtain $p_r$ from the hamiltonian in terms of the energy $E$ and the angular momentum:
\begin{equation}
p_r = \pm \sqrt{2m\left(E+\frac{e^2}{r}\right)-\frac{l^2}{r}}.
\end{equation}

Considering elliptical orbits? $\dot{r} = 0$ and $p_r = 0$ so from the expression above I can obtain a $r_{max}=r_+$ and a $r_{min}=r_-$ which will be my integration limits

\begin{equation}
r = -\frac{e^2}{2E} \pm \frac{\sqrt{m\left(me^4+2l^2\right)}}{2mE}.
\end{equation}

Then I have

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\int p_r dr = \displaystyle\int_{r_-}^{r_+} \sqrt{2m\left(E+\frac{e^2}{r}\right)-\frac{l^2}{r}} dr = k h \text{   (Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization)}
\end{equation}

and doing some basic algebra I can write

\begin{equation}
\displaystyle\int_{r_-}^{r_+} \frac{\sqrt{ar^2+br+c}}{r} dr = kh 
\end{equation}

with $a = 2mE$, $b= 2me^2$ and $c=-l^2$.

I think that solving this integral and using the quantization condition about the angular variable found before I could obtain the energy levels in terms of the quantum numbers $n$ and $k$ but I am really stucked in how to solve that integral. Maybe I'm wrong about my way of solving this problem.
I will be very grateful for any help

Comment: see https://p6pr0blems.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/problem-8-14-griffiths/

Comment: I think you lost a square in your formula for $p_r$.
It should be $-\frac{l^2}{r^2}$ under the root.